# imu not measuring acceleration and angular rates in cmd_vel mode

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using cmd_vel to command the drc robot in the qual1 world. I want to fuse in IMU data. The /atlas/imu/angular_velocity/z remains small even though the true robot is turning at upto 5 rad/s. Am I missing something ?

Should the IMU not measure the movement ?

regards
c29

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2186/imu-not-measuring-acceleration-and-angular-rates-in-cmd_vel-mode/) by [c29](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/278/c29/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [c29](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/278/c29/) on 2013-04-01**:
By the way I am using drc 2.2. Should I really be using the nightly builds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`cmd_vel` uses the fake teleop which does not use physics, it simply "teleports" the robot, so imu will not work.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0